# Railway Nodemon Permission Denied

Tags: node.js, express, backend, nodemon

when i try to run my application on Railway, i keep getting a loop of sh: 1: nodemon permission denied errors until it eventually crashes.
Here is the error:

`sh: 1: nodemon: Permission denied npm WARN config production Use` --omit=dev` instead.

> railway-test@0.0.0 start
> nodemon models/mongo_test.js`

Here is my package.js where i define the start command:

```
{
  "name": "railway-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon mongo_test.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.5",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.1"
  }
}
```

Im quite new to Backend development like this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

I've tried moving the mongo_test.ts and .js into the same directory as the package.json and it hasn't worked. On railway, it successfully deploys the project but after showing the permission denied error like 40 times it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve the "--omit=dev" you can add this to your "Dockerfile"

```
RUN npm install --omit=dev
```

Regarding the other question, i usually use "node file.js" for production and "nodemon file.js" for development, because idk nodemon in production, at least for me, is a little bit tricky.